# LiteDB: Команда, которая показывает какой SQL генерирует LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Есть команда в LiteDB, которая показывает какой запрос создаёт LINQ?
Я знаю, что в ef есть такая

```
Context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

Есть что-то наподобие???

Comment: Вы уверены, что там вообще SQL используется?

Comment: LiteDB не использует SQL. В LiteDB вообще нет внутреннего языка запросов. / Если использовать LINQ to Objects - что генерируется? Вот то же самое и здесь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Окей, как вывести лог, что происходит? Какой json формируется.

Comment: Или что там он формирует